# Deriving the result $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid A=a] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[Y\cdot\mathbf{1}\{A=a\}]}{P(A=a)}$

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

It is a well known result that
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y\mid A=a] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[Y\cdot\mathbf{1}\{A=a\}]}{P(A=a)}.
$$
To derive this result, one would proceed as below:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Y\cdot\mathbf{1}\{A=a\}] & = \sum_{a'} \mathbb{E}[Y\cdot\mathbf{1}\{A=a\}|A=a']P(A=a')\\
& =  0 + \cdots + \mathbb{E}[Y\cdot\mathbf{1}\{A=a\}|A=a]P(A=a)\\
& = \mathbb{E}[Y|A=a]P(A=a).
\end{align}
$$
The result this follows from the last line as
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y\mid A=a] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[Y\cdot\mathbf{1}\{A=a\}]}{P(A=a)}.
$$
My question is whether the following would also be a valid derivation:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Y\mid A=a] & =  \frac{\sum_{y} y \cdot P(Y=y,A=a)}{P(A=a)} \\
& = \frac{\sum_{y} \sum_{a'} y\cdot \mathbf{1}\{A=a\} \cdot P(Y=y,A=a')}{P(A=a)} \\
& = \frac{\mathbb{E}[Y\cdot\mathbf{1}\{A=a\}]}{P(A=a)}.
\end{align}
$$
I believe that the first and second line of the above derivation should be equal as I have restricted the summation $\sum_{a'}$ to only allow for one non-zero term to be summed up. Furthermore, the second line fits the definition of a bivariate expectation such that this derivation should hold.

If this derivation is correct, it would seem a bit more straightforward than the standard one given at the beginning of this question.

Comment: The summation over $y$ only works if $Y$ is a discrete random variable.